# Coding style in STM32 HAL code

Tags: stm32, c, hal-library

While I was reading the STM32 HAL drivers for timers I found this macro:

```
#define __HAL_TIM_DISABLE(__HANDLE__) \
                    do { \
                      if (((__HANDLE__)->Instance->CCER & TIM_CCER_CCxE_MASK) == 0U) \
                      { \
                        (__HANDLE__)->Instance->CR1 &= ~(TIM_CR1_CEN); \
                      } \
                    } while(0)
```

Since the while part is always wrong there should be basically no loop, and the do-while seems redundant to me. But since they distribute it in the HAL like this, I suppose there is some point? Can anyone point out which?

Comment: This should be asked over at the main stack overflow site, but would be closed as a dup of something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block).

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree :) Should I best delete the question, or what is the most apropriate way to deal with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `do { something; } while (0)` is a typical pattern in macros, where you want to make sure that all instructions get executed.

Example why this is important:

```
#define MY_MACRO() do_something1(); do_something2()
```

This will work:

```
MY_MACRO();
```

but this will not work as intended:

```
if (some_condition) MY_MACRO();
```

because it will be preprocessed into:

```
if (some_condition) do_something1(); do_something2();
```

The second statement will be executed no matter what the condition said.

A `do { ... } while(0)` is just a convenient way to make a block of code. It will be optimized out by the compiler anyway, so there is actually no looping involved and no runtime overhead.

Comment: Thanks again. I like your answer better concerning understandability from the SO one that brhans linked. But one important think they mentioned over there, which your answer is missing is the merit, that `do{}while(0)` gives you over using braces `{ ...code... }` in your macro, since `{}` already is a compound statement, and extra semicolon would thus break usage in an if-body, but the do-while with no semicolon attached allows usage in this situation. Thank you all very much, learning something new every day here ;)